# How to clean up build cache in Docker (size is 15 Gb but reclaimable space is 0)?

Tags: docker

I met a strange situation: Docker build cache is not reclaimable and I can't clean it up.

That's what I have after running `docker system prune --all`:

```
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          0         0         0B        0B
Containers      0         0         0B        0B
Local Volumes   0         0         0B        0B
Build Cache     40        40        14.59GB   0B
```

Therefore, I have no containers and no images - but I have some dangling build cache.
How to clean or reclaim it?

Answer (score 0):

My steps to solve the problem:

1. `docker builder prune -a` cleaned ~2 Gb of my space, but ~12.5 Gb were still not reclaimed. I saw some images by running `docker buildx du` but couldn't clean them.
2. I've restarted my computer. After that I found all 12.5 Gb in the RECLAIMED section, and `docker system prune --all` cleaned all this space.
   I suspect that I had some non-stopped processes because I did some experiments with some mount options in Dockerfile, sometimes I had a freeze of building and I interrupted building process by Ctrl-Z.